# How to bind the kendo grid cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have used a kendo grid in my application.
In the grid, a row contains a dropdownlist. when i select the value in the dropdownlist the other cell in the row get updated.
But i'm trying to update  the other cell using javascript.I can't get the solution for this.

can anyone help me,please?

my kendo grid in razor:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<models.employee>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.name).ClientTemplate(
                    "<input type='hidden' name='items[#= index(data)#].name' value='#= getLine(data)#' /> <p>#= getLine(data)#</p>"
                );
                columns.Bound(c => c.Emp_num).EditorTemplateName("EmpEditor").ClientTemplate(
                        "#= Emp_num #" +
                        "<input type='hidden' class='Emp-select' name='items[#= index(data)#].Emp_num' id='items[#= index(data)#].Emp_num' value='#= Emp_num #' />"
                    );
                columns.Bound(c => c.description).EditorTemplateName("DescripEditor").ClientTemplate(
                    "#= description #" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='items[#= index(data)#].description' data-fill='items[#= index(data)#].description' value='#= description #' />"
                );
columns.Bound(c => c.address).EditorTemplateName("addressEditor").ClientTemplate(
                "#= address #" +
                "<input type='hidden' name='items[#= index(data)#].address' value='#= address #' data-fill='items[#= index(data)#].address' value='' />"
            );
    })
```

In EmpEditor.cshtml:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("Emp_num")
    .OptionLabel("Select Employee Number...")
    .DataValueField("Emp_num")
    .DataTextField("Emp_num")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Employee"])
    .Events(e => e.Select("changes"))
)
```

javascript :

```
function changes(e)
{
    var Emp_num = this.dataItem(e.item).Emp_num;  // which gives the employee num

    getEmp(Emp_num, function (emp) {    //this function retrieve the details of employee for the particular employee number

        var Employee = emp;

        //here I need the code for update the values of Employee.description to description cell and Employee.address to address cell


    });
}
```

Comment: You should post some code to help people see what you're doing. It would provide some context and your problem would get a lot more attention. Also this is quite a broad problem requiring knowledge of Kendo UI, JavaScript (jQuery maybe...) and HTML. You will usually find you get better responses if you keep it reasonably focussed.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I imagine you have some kind of template which defines your dropdownlist as part of your kendo-grid column definitions, right? You need to write a JavaScript function that updates the cell and add it to the onChange for this dropdownlist. The Kendo docs probably cover that.